# Javascript - order an array of objects by date in each object

Tags: javascript

So basically I have an array like so:

```
const data = [
    { name: "John Doe", dob: "2021-07-06T09:45:07.125Z" },
    { name: "Jane Doe", dob: "2021-07-06T09:44:34.121Z" },
    { name: "John Wick", dob: "2021-07-06T09:50:17.313Z" }
];
```

I need to display this data in a table, so I am mapping through the array and creating a row, but I need the youngest person to be first. I tried doing like `.sort()` but couldn't get it to work

```
{data.sort((a,b) => b.dob- a.dob
```

Comment: "I tried doing like .sort()" Could you show us the code you tried?

Comment: Does this question help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/10123953/14032355

Comment: @phuzi I tried `data.sort((a,b)=> new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date))`

Comment: You need to add that code to the question and explain what you're expecting and what actually happens. Could you also put some sample dates in the example rather than `"Date in ISO format"`